# How to handle the content of text field using Knockout.js custom binding?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a simple text field with inital value 0.00. But, when I delete the content of text field and focus goes to another element, the previous format 0.00 was returned. I'd like to have empty field after I delete its content. The code looks as following:

1) Template:

```
<div class="group">
    <p class="ds-field-name top width-auto">To</p>
    <input class="ds-input width-fixed-quarter" type="text" data-bind="moneyInfinity: fields.amountTo, moneyMultiplier: 100, moneyABS: true"/>
</div>
```

2) Custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.moneyInfinity = {
    format(data) {
        if (typeof data === 'undefined' || data === null) return '';
        const num = parseFloat(data) || 0;
        return num.toFixed(2);
    },
    init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        const value = valueAccessor();
        const bindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        const multiplier = (bindings.moneyMultiplier !== '' && undefined !== bindings.moneyMultiplier)
            ? bindings.moneyMultiplier : 1.00;

        const abs = bindings.moneyABS || false;

        const format = ko.bindingHandlers.money.format;

        $(element).change(function () {
            const $this = $(this);

            if ($this.val() === '') {
                $this.val(null);
                value(null);

                return;
            }

            const normalized = ($this.val() || '0').replace(',', '.');
            const newData = format(abs ? Math.abs(normalized) : normalized);

            $this.val(multiplier);
            value(newData * multiplier);
        });
    },
    update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        const main = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        const value = valueAccessor();
        const bindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        const multiplier = bindings.moneyMultiplier || 1.00;
        const abs = bindings.moneyABS || false;

        const format = ko.bindingHandlers.money.format;

        if (value() === '') {
            return;
        }

        $(element).val(format(abs ? Math.abs(value() / multiplier) : value() / multiplier));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main reason it keeps going back to "0.00" is that the UI is updating the model, which then causes the model to update the UI again. In your binding when the model updates it always formats the output to the UI so it's seeing that part as blank and sends "0.00" back to the UI.

I had to make a few other changes to get it working, but here's an updated binding:

```js
function format(data) {
        if (typeof data === 'undefined' || data === null) return '';
        const num = parseFloat(data) || 0;
        return num.toFixed(2);
    }
    
ko.bindingHandlers.moneyInfinity = {
    init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        const value = valueAccessor();
        const bindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        const multiplier = (bindings.moneyMultiplier !== '' && undefined !== bindings.moneyMultiplier)
            ? bindings.moneyMultiplier : 1.00;

        const abs = bindings.moneyABS || false;

        //const format = ko.bindingHandlers.money.format;

        $(element).change(function () {
            const $this = $(this);
 
            if ($this.val() === '') {
                //$this.val(null); //Not sure what this was supposed to do
                value(null);

                return;
            }

            const normalized = ($this.val() || '0').replace(',', '.');
            const newData = format(abs ? Math.abs(normalized) : normalized);

            //$this.val(multiplier); //Not sure what this was supposed to do
            value(newData * multiplier);
            value.notifySubscribers(); //force an update even if value  evaluates the same. "0" == "0.00"
        });
    },
    update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        const main = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        const value = valueAccessor();
        const bindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        const multiplier = bindings.moneyMultiplier || 1.00;
        const abs = bindings.moneyABS || false;

        //const format = ko.bindingHandlers.money.format;

        if (!value() && typeof(value()) != "number") { //ignore null, undefined, and blank
            return;
        }

        $(element).val(format(abs ? Math.abs(value() / multiplier) : value() / multiplier));
    }
};

function viewModel(){
  this.fields = {
    amountTo: ko.observable('')
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="group">
    <p class="ds-field-name top width-auto">To</p>
    <input class="ds-input width-fixed-quarter" type="text" data-bind="moneyInfinity: fields.amountTo, moneyMultiplier: 100, moneyABS: true"/>
</div>
```